# Python get current partitioned data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading parquet files from s3 partitioned by date with Python and Pandas. Is there a way to get the current date in my path instead of specifying the folder date = 2020-09-11. Here's what I got for now.

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

source_bucket = 'some_bucket'
source_path = 'some_folder/date=2020-09-11'
bucket_uri = f's3a://{source_bucket}/{source_path}'

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(bucket_uri, filesystem=fs, use_legacy_dataset= False) 
table = dataset.read()
df = table.to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use datetime package

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 9, 11, 30, 890810)
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2020-09-11'

>>> ds = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

>>> source_bucket = 'some_bucket'
>>> source_path = f"some_folder/date={ds}"
>>> bucket_uri = f's3a://{source_bucket}/{source_path}'

>>> bucket_uri
's3a://some_bucket/some_folder/date=2020-09-11'
```